# TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Word in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am creating a `Word` class and I am getting an error:

> TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Word

Here is the *irb* code:

```
irb(main):016:0> class Word
irb(main):017:1>  def palindrome?(string)
irb(main):018:2>   string == string.reverse
irb(main):019:2>  end
irb(main):020:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):021:0> w = Word.new
=> #<Word:0x4a8d970>
irb(main):022:0> w.palindrome?("foobar")
=> false
irb(main):023:0> w.palindrome?("level")
=> true
irb(main):024:0> class Word < String
irb(main):025:1>  def palindrome?
irb(main):026:2>    self == self.reverse
irb(main):027:2>  end
irb(main):028:1> end
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Word
 from (irb):24
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Looks like second `class Word` is conflicting with the first one. Not sure how to clear that without closing IRB and reopening though.

Comment: And as an FYI I tend to do classes, loops and more complex blocks in a script and run the script than use the IRB.

Comment: A good lesson for us also in that this would do the same thing in any Ruby file. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**A thumb rule for *irb* (either way `irb` or `rails console`)**

If you are creating the same class twice with inheritance (superclass), exit the irb instance and create it again. Why this? Because otherwise class conflicts will happen.

In your case, you are using Windows (found from the question), so just type `exit` on DOS prompt and again type `irb` or `rails console` and create your Word class and it should work. Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Is this actually a solution to the problem. Yes you may not run into the error if you exit and reenter the console, but doesn't the error indicate that there is something wrong with the code?

Comment: `f you are creating the same class twice with inheritance`! Yeah! My case was with the outoloaders.

Answer (score 22):

The reason it gives you a superclass mismatch error is because you have already defined the `Word` class as inheriting from [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html)

```
class Word
...
end
```

In Ruby (like in most dynamic languages) you can [monkey-patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) classes by reopening the definition and modifying the class.  However, in your instance, when you are reopening the class you are also attempting to redefine the class as inheriting from the super class `String`.

```
class Word < String
...
end
```

Once a class and it's inheritance structure have been defined, you cannot define it again.

As a few people have said, exiting and restarting irb will allow you to start from scratch in defining the `Word` class.

Comment: _Once a class and it's inheritance structure have been defined, you cannot define it again._ This is what I needed

Answer (score 17):

link664 has clearly explained the problem.

However, there's an easier fix without quitting irb (and losing all your other work).
You can delete an existing class definition this way.

```
irb(main):051:0> Object.send(:remove_const, :Word)
```

and you can verify with:

```
irb(main):052:0> Word.public_instance_methods
```

which should return:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Word
from (irb):52
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to bypass this issue is to encapsulate both classes between different modules:

```
> module M
>     class Word
>         def palindrome?(string)
>             string == string.reverse
>         end
>     end
> end
=> nil
> w = M::Word.new
=> #<Word:0x4a8d970>
> w.palindrome?("foobar")
=> false
> w.palindrome?("level")
=> true
> module N
>     class Word < String
>         def palindrome?
>             self == self.reverse
>         end
>     end
> end
> N::Word.new("kayak").palindrome?
=> true
```

Comment: I plugged this code into `irb` and got the same error: *TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Word*

Comment: I don't remember my answer very well, I think I meant using two different module names (`M` and then `N`). That is a trick I used to use, I'll update my answer accordingly.