# Why I use Rails model concerns will get the superclass mismatch errors with class in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I use Puma and Rails 4.2.

My concern is set up like this:

```
Class Order
  module Chartable
     ...
  end
end
```

The `order class` is set up like this:

```
Class Order
  include Chartable
end
```

In development, the code showed no errors, but in the production I got the error:

> Unable to load application: TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Order.

I don't know why this error happens, and after consulting some documentation, I think the error comes from Puma's `set :puma_preload_app, true` - is it right?

How can I fix this error and `preload_app` always set to true?

Comment: Is that actually what is in your files? Doesn't look like valid ruby at the moment to me

Comment: Any particular reason `Chartable` is declared withing `Order`?

Comment: @FrederickCheung My files just like `model/concerns/order/chartable.rb`

Comment: @jcm Because `Chartable` only work in `Order`.

Comment: Is that the complete code?  This [other question with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814282/typeerror-superclass-mismatch-for-class-word-ruby) happened because a class was defined twice with different superclasses.

Comment: @jcm I think it is not the same that question, because work find and no errors in the development environment.

Comment: This is most likely due to file load order. The class is probably first being defined from within the concern file. Then when the model file is loaded, I'm guessing the model inherits from ActiveRecord meaning that you are trying to add the inheritance after the class has already been defined. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512023/ruby-on-rails-3-superclass-mismatch-for-class#answer-9700350)