# `<module:Rails>': superclass mismatch for class Server (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814282/typeerror-superclass-mismatch-for-class-word-ruby) and several others question, but their problems are not similar to mine.

I have added the following code to the `config/boot.rb` , to run my server on port 8081

```
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge({Port: 8081})
    end
  end
end
```

Then I tried to run `rails s`, and i face with this erorr:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>': superclass mismatch for class Server (TypeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A better way to do what you want:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'

module DefaultOptions
  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: 8081)
  end
end

Rails::Server.prepend(DefaultOptions)
```

The reason for the error message is because you are attempting to redefine the `Rails::Server` class and changing it's inheritance structure. `Rails::Server` inherits from `::Rack::Server`, however your code is trying to say it no longer does. Therefore, you get your superclass mismatch error.

Comment: Just a success report: this works in Rails 5. I've added this snippet into `config/boot.rb`.

Answer (score 5):

For Rails **5.1** the following line in `config/boot.rb` will do the trick:

```
ENV['PORT'] = '8081'
```

[Link to the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb#L187).

Answer (score 2):

In **`Rails 5.2`**

in `config/puma.rb` I added this code.

```rb
#port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
bind        'tcp://0.0.0.0:3001'
```

And it works!