# TypeError (superclass mismatch for class QueryCustomFieldColumn)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I am trying to add class QueryCustomFieldColumn < QueryColumn I am getting the below error.

Any anybody assist me on this?

> TypeError (superclass mismatch for class QueryCustomFieldColumn)

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: elaborate on what's `QueryColumn`

Comment: QueryColumn is one class just I am inheriting from that class QueryColumn

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9814493/157943 - if you're getting this error in `irb`, try exiting and restarting it. If you're getting it in Rails, try stopping and restarting your server.

Comment: Thanks  gmcnaughton

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you run sudo grep -r "OrderedOptions" . in your ruby project folder, you would see that other class have the same name as OrderedOptions if you found it, you should change the file’s name.